# proper way to start and interface with a service and statusbar/notification

Tags: android, service, notifications

I have a broadcast receiver that works fine but now I want to send send notifications to status bar. Since BroadcastReceiver cannot do it directly it looks like I need to create a service to do that for me correct?

So I created a service using the examples provided at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Other than a few small tweaks  it's that code.  I start the service from the broadcast receiver  with
 context.startService(new Intent(context, AlertUser.class));

What happened is it did put out the msg in the status bar. then when I did a clear and had it generate a new msg the service code did not execute.  Do I interact with he service differently once started? From what I read no if part of same process.

Also how would I share information like a string from the the BroadcastReceiver to the service to that it is info to display in the notification?

Thanks,

Frank

Answer (score 0):

> Since BroadcastReceiver cannot do it directly it looks like I need to create a service to do that for me correct?

A `BroadcastReceiver` can display a `Notification`.

> Do I interact with he service differently once started?

Not really. If you are sending commands to the service via `startService()`, those commands are received in `onStartCommand()`.

> how would I share information like a string from the the BroadcastReceiver to the service to that it is info to display in the notification?

Pass it in an extra on the `Intent` you pass to `startService()`, and retrieve it out of the `Intent` in `onStartCommand()`.

Comment: From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html says " An Activity or Service can initiate a status bar notification. " lead me to beleive a BroadcastReceiver could not perform that action. I'm fairly new to andorid development how am I sending commands to the service via the intent I send it?

Comment: I think duh is in order for me, lol I should do something like this correct? <br/>   Intent servIntent = new Intent(context, AlertUser.class);  <br/> 
  servIntent.putExtra("AlertMsg", ac.toString() + " Security Alert");  <br/> 
  //start a service to send a notification to the user via the status bar
  context.startService(servIntent);  <br/>  Then in the service do?  <br/>  alertMsg = intent.getStringExtra("AlertMsg");

Comment: @captfrank: "lead me to beleive a BroadcastReceiver could not perform that action" -- the documentation is incorrect on that point. Your extra handling in your second comment seems fine.